# How to convert 3 numbers (or axes) into one number

Tags: probability, geometry, metric-spaces, 3d, machine-learning

I'm sorry if my explication is not quite the best but I'm not sure how to explain this in mathematical terms.

So I'm working on a Machine Learning project where I'm trying to get the emotions from one text. Each emotion will have a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means that emotion those not exist, and 1 means it's 100% that.

For example, I could have:

**positive** 0.8466, **neutral** 0.1458, **negative** 0.0076

This been my 3 base emotions that I am getting from any text.

Is there any way in which I can convert those numbers into a single one from a spectrum between -1 and 1. That would mean if the number is closer to 0 then the most powerful emotion from that text is **negative**, if it's closer to 0 then it's neutral, and also if it's closer to 1 that means it's positive.

Those any of you know how can I achieve something like this? I was thinking to consider each of the emotions as an axis into a 3d space, but I'm not sure how could I calculate that point in space.

Comment: The end result is that it is entirely your choice.  There are uncountably infinitely many functions from $[0,1]^3$ to $[-1,1]$.  As for a suggestion... try simply $f(\text{pos},\text{neut},\text{neg})=\text{pos}-\text{neg}$

Comment: But if I'm going to do just this pos-neg... In this case, I'm just going to ignore the neutral value, and I'm not quite sure this is a good decision in some corner cases. Could you give me any other hint?

Comment: Do the three numbers always add up to 1?  They do in your example, so if that's the case, you are looking at a 2-d plane in the 3-d space to start with that you are looking to reduce to 1-d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u$ be the negative weight, $v$ the neutral weight, and $w$ the positive weight.  The score you want is of form
$$S = \frac{f(w) - h(u)}{f(w) + g(v) + h(u)}$$
where $f$, $g$, and $h$ are nonnegative weighting functions.

The simplest one is linear: $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x$, $h(x) = x$, so
$$S = \frac{w - u}{w + v + u}$$

Almost as simple is a monomial form of some degree $p$, $f(x) = x^p$, $g(x) = x^p$, $h(x) = x^p$, so
$$S = \frac{w^p - u^p}{w^p + v^p + u^p}$$
where $p \gt 0$.  Obviously, for $p = 1$ it is the linear above.

Comment: this is perfect, thx :D

Answer (score 0):

A very natural solution is to weight the values. For example take $f(x)=1 \times$ *positive* $+ 0 \times $ *neutral* $ + (-1) \times $ *negative*. It's easy to show that $f(x) \in [-1,1]$ and why you can ignore *neutral*.